# InspIRCd with gnutls

Tags: server, irc, ssl

I'm receiving an error trying to setup an IRC server with InspIRCd using gnutls for SSL connections.

- Ubuntu Server 11.10 (Kernel 3.0.0-14-server)
- InspIRCd-1.1.22+Azeitao r0

Logfile;

```
==> /var/log/inspircd.log <==
Fri Jan 13 12:03:44 2012: Done reading configuration file.
Fri Jan 13 12:03:44 2012: Unable to load /usr/lib/inspircd/modules/m_ssl_gnutls.so: /usr/lib/inspircd/modules/m_ssl_gnutls.so: undefined symbol: gnutls_x509_crt_get_issuer_dn
Fri Jan 13 12:03:44 2012: There was an error loading the module 'm_ssl_gnutls.so': Loader/Linker error: /usr/lib/inspircd/modules/m_ssl_gnutls.so: undefined symbol: gnutls_x509_crt_get_issuer_dn
```

The gnutls packages that are currently on the system;

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gnutls
gnutls-bin                                      install
libcurl3-gnutls                                 install
libgnutls-dev                                   install
libgnutls26                                     install
libgnutlsxx26                                   install
libneon27-gnutls                                install
```

inspircd.conf excerpt

```
<module name="m_ssl_gnutls.so"> 
<bind address="192.168.1.2" port="6697" type="clients" ssl="gnutls">                                                                      
<ssl_cert name="cert1" certfile="/etc/ssl/certs/server.cer" keyfile="/etc/ssl/private/server.key">
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

Perhaps your syntax is wrong?

```
<bind address="10.0.0.10" port="6667" type="clients" ssl="gnutls">

<module name="m_ssl_gnutls.so"> 

<gnutls cafile="" crlfile="" certfile="/etc/inspircd/ssl.cert" keyfile="/etc/inspircd/ssl.key" dh_bits="2048">
```

Also, make sure you stripped your passphrase that wraps your ssl key file (so it can boot)

See:

```
Archive:  http://85.13.254.50/index.php

New Incomplete Docs:  https://github.com/inspircd/wiki/wiki/_pages
```

Answer (score 1):

The apt packages for InspIRCd are heavily out of date and are full of bugs like the one you have encountered. It is recommended you install InspIRCd from the tarball release. The latest tarball release can be downloaded from https://github.com/danieldg/inspircd/zipball/v2.0.5

If you have any issues feel free to visit irc.chatspike.net #inspircd and chat with the developers.